# Want to restore to my default DNS server settings

Tags: server, internet, dns

I recently tried changing my DNS settings and while doing that I altered a few settings due to which I'm not able to access Internet on my Wired connection.
I tried editing the `resolv.conf` as follows

```
sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
```

After few unknown alterations my Internet was gone.

Please help.

Comment: Can you display what is written in your resolv.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

First 2 lines of /etc/resolv.conf:

`# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)`

`#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`

Change your DNS setting in your network manager or if you don't use GUI in `/etc/network/interfaces`, so they won't be overwitten.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Right-click on Network Icon and click on Edit Connections.

Choose the type of connection you have, Wireless or Wired connections.

Under Wireless or Wired highlight the connection you use and click on Edit.

Inside the editing window that opens click on the IPv4 Settings tab.

Under IPv4 Settings, change the Method to Automatic (DHCP) addresses only.

Put these name server addresses as your DNS Servers:

208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220

Click OK and reboot.

```
http://welcome.opendns.com/
```